# Find maximum w.r.t. substring within each group of formatted strings

Tags: regex, scala, scala-collections

I am struggling to find solution for a scenario. I have few files in a directory. lets say

```
vbBaselIIIData_201802_3_d.data.20180405.txt.gz    
vbBaselIIIData_201802_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz   
vbBaselIIIData_201803_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz  
vbBaselIIIData_201803_5_d.data.20180405.txt.gz
```

Here suppose the single digit number after the second underscore is called runnumber. I have to pick only files with latest runnumber. so in this case I need to pick only two out of the four files and put it in a mutable scala list. The ListBuffer should contain :

```
vbBaselIIIData_201802_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz  
vbBaselIIIData_201803_5_d.data.20180405.txt.gz
```

Can anybody suggest me how to implement this. I am using Scala, but only algorithm is also appreciated. What could be the right sets of datastructure we can use? What are the functions we need to implement? Any suggestions.

Comment: You've just said that you want to store a bunch of `String`s in a `ListBuffer`. Given this requirement, how is *"What could be the right sets of datastructure we can use?"* even a question?

Comment: how can i filter the ListBuffer that's the question here

Comment: Is the run number a set number that you already know?  What I mean is are you looking for something_numbers_runnumber_whatever...   where runnumber is always 5?

Comment: it's the runnumber can be any number. but we have to pick only the string containing latest runnumber. for example we hav vbBaselIIIData_201803_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz and vbBaselIIIData_201803_5_d.data.20180405.txt.gz . in this case we will pick vbBaselIIIData_201803_5_d.data.20180405.txt.gz for processing. the first one will be ignored.

Comment: could there be 2 files with same run number for the same month but different dates? like `vbBaselIIIData_201803_5_d.data.20180405.txt.gz` and `vbBaselIIIData_201803_5_d.data.20180406.txt.gz`. and if so, which one should be picked?

Comment: @Matt.G this situation won't come in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hopefully somewhat inspiring proposal that demonstrates a whole bunch of different language features and useful methods on collections:

```
val list = List(
  "vbBaselIIIData_201802_3_d.data.20180405.txt.gz",
  "vbBaselIIIData_201802_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz",
  "vbBaselIIIData_201803_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz",
  "vbBaselIIIData_201803_5_d.data.20180405.txt.gz"
)

val P = """[^_]+_(\d+)_(\d+)_.*""".r
val latest = list
  .map { str => {val P(id, run) = str; (str, id, run.toInt) }}
  .groupBy(_._2)                // group by id
  .mapValues(_.maxBy(_._3)._1)  // find the last run for each id
  .values                       // throw away the id
  .toList
  .sorted                       // restore ordering, mostly for cosmetic purposes

latest foreach println
```

Brief explanation of the not-entirely-trivial parts that you might have missed when reading an introduction to Scala:

- `"regex pattern".r` converts a string into a compiled regex pattern
- A block `{ stmt1 ; stmt2 ; stmt3 ; ... ; stmtN; result }` evaluates to the last expression `result`
- Extractor syntax can be used for compiled regex patterns
- `val P(id, run) = str` matches the second and third `_`-separated values
- `_.maxBy(_._3)._1` finds the triple with highest run number, then extracts the first component `str` again

Output:

```
vbBaselIIIData_201802_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz
vbBaselIIIData_201803_5_d.data.20180405.txt.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file-names as a list, like:

```
val list = List("vbBaselIIIData_201802_3_d.data.20180405.txt.gz"   
, "vbBaselIIIData_201802_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz"   
, "vbBaselIIIData_201803_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz"  
, "vbBaselIIIData_201803_5_d.data.20180405.txt.gz")
```

Then you can do:

```
list.map{f => 
  val s = f.split("_").toList
     (s(1), f)
   }.groupBy(_._1)
   .map(_._2.max)
   .values
```

This returns:

```
MapLike.DefaultValuesIterable(vbBaselIIIData_201803_5_d.data.20180405.txt.gz, vbBaselIIIData_201802_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz)
```

as you wanted.

Comment: the requirement is to get `vbBaselIIIData_201802_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz`. this gives you `vbBaselIIIData_201803_4_d.data.20180405.txt.gz`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what performance needs you have, even though you're mentioning an 'algorithm'.

Provided you don't have more specific needs, something like this is easy to do with Scala's Collection API. Even if you were dealing with huge directories, you could probably achieve some good performance characteristics by moving to Streams (at least in memory usage).

So assuming you have a function like `def getFilesFromDir(path: String): List[String]` where the `List[String]` is a list of filenames, you need to do the following:

- Group files by date (`List[String] => Map[String, List[String]]`
- Extract the Runnumbers, preserving the original filename (`List[String] => List[(String, Int)]`)
- Select the max Runnumber (`List[(String, Int)] => (String, Int)`)
- Map to just the filename (`(String, Int) => String`)
- Select just the values of the resulting Map (`Map[Date, String] => String`)

(*Note*: if you want to go the pure functional route, you'll want a function something like `def getFilesFromDir(path: String): IO[List[String]]`)

With Scala's Collections API you can achieve the above with something like this:

```
def extractDate(fileName: String): String = ???
def extractRunnumber(fileName: String): String = ???

def getLatestRunnumbersFromDir(path: String): List[String] =
  getFilesFromDir(path)
    .groupBy(extractDate) // List[String] => Map[String, List[String]]
    .mapValues(selectMaxRunnumber) // Map[String, List[String]] => Map[String, String]
    .values // Map[String, String] => List[String]

def selectMaxRunnumber(fileNames: List[String]): String =
  fileNames.map(f => f -> extractRunnumber(f))
    .maxBy(p => p._2)
    ._1
```

I've left the `extractDate` and `extractRunnumber` implementations blank. These can be done using simple regular expressions — let me know if you're having trouble with that.